# Python: Precomputing/caching parts of of functions

Tags: python, function, caching

Let's consider the following function in Python (it's only a dummy example):

```
from math import factorial

def f(x, param):
    init = factorial(param)
    return x**param / init
```

This function is called many times inside the main code with different values of `x` but with the same value of `param`. However, the value of `param` is arbitrary and not known beforehand.

How can I precompute or cache the value of `init` at the first function call so that it does not need to be recomputed with every function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the lru_cache from functools to cache the results of the factorial call. The following example creates a custom cached version of factorial from math.factorial,

```
import math
import functools

@functools.lru_cache()
def factorial(n):
    return math.factorial(n)

def f(x, param):
    init = factorial(param)
    return x**param / init
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the default value of param to be a global variable. Then, when you run the program and set param, just change the value

```
default = 0
def f(x, param=default):
    if param==default:
        init = default_init
    else:
        init = factorial(param)
    return x**param / init

def main():
    global default
    default=arbitary_value
    global default_init = factorial(default)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a class with init and param as attributes like following:

```
from math import factorial

class f:
  def __init__(self, param):
    self.init = factorial(param)
    self.param = param

  def __call__(self, x):
    return x**self.param / self.init


a = f(10) # __init__

for i in range(10):
  print(a(i))  # __call__
```